What is $x^{y^z}$ called? What is the fastest level of growth?
What are higher level exponents called like $x^{x^x}$.  Is there any limit to exponential growth like $x^{inf^{inf^inf}}$? Would something like factorial exponential growth be faster: ${inf}!^{inf!^{inf!^inf!^{...}}}$.  Are these called double, triple, quadruple exponents, etc?  And when does growth at high rates all look about the same (straight upward growth)?  Would straight upward growth be the fastest?  Simply $x=y$?

Google "tetration" and "power tower".

I meant $y=1$ not $x=y$ which would be linear growth.  And I guess $y=1$ would not grow in $x$.

While $y^z$ is exponential in $z$, $x^{y^z}$ is double exponential. We can keep going.

I know that {x^x^x^x^x....} n times is called Tetration. it is however early used, because it doesn't really have many applications. the fastest level of growth is either the Ackerman function, or the busy beaver. hope that helps

Literally my first Google hit for "grows faster than busy beaver" is Is busy beaver the fastest growing function known to man? on the CS StackExchange. Answers point out, among many more sophisticated examples, that the square of the busy beaver function obviously grows faster.
